# ill effects of reducing TCP socket connection retries

Tags: sockets, tcp, embedded-linux, ipv4

I have a tcp client in embedded Linux device,to establish connection with the server while the device is in running mode.

We have a program mode, where all activities have to seize, as the system parameters will be changed.

The way I designed it was create a socket on boot and close the connection and reopen the connections after coming out of program mode.

My problem is the 'connect' , during the boot up is blocking for more than 2 minutes , and it keeps on increasing as time goes on making the system sluggish.

someone told me that, changing the 'tcp_syn_retries' will eventually reduce the hog time and I tried and found that it will reduce the blocking time to under '1 ms'

Can anyone tell me about the possible implications of this change?

Also, can you suggest me how to implement the connect in a non blocking mode ? because the one i tried didn't establish the connection.

Any comments / response will be helpful.

Edit: As TCP has a 3way handshake, this would reduce the number of SYNC requests to the TCP server during the TCP handshaking. As a result , connecting to the remote TCP servers on a slow or sluggish connection will not be reliable
This is the info i got out of from googling. how much is too much ? Any suggestions welcome.